# How to get a list of AWS regions programmatically in Go SDK V2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

AWS removed `endpoints` package from [Go SDK V2](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/migrating/#endpoints). Is there a way to get a list of AWS regions using Go SDK V2?

In V1 you could write something like this:

```
    import "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/endpoints"
    ...
    ...
    
        partitions := endpoints.DefaultPartitions()
        for _, p := range partitions {
            for region := range p.Regions() {
                validRegions[region] = struct{}{}
            }
        }
    
    ...
    ...
```

However, this seems no longer possible. I did notice an autogenerated [json](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/59774b18837c670a2c5327ae244c664459462697/codegen/smithy-aws-go-codegen/src/main/resources/software/amazon/smithy/aws/go/codegen/endpoints.json) which seems to contain all the partitions, however I can't seem to figure out how to get the list of available regions in the code.

Is there a way to do this in Go SDK V2?

Comment: Have you got any alternative?

Answer (score 4):

There is a `DescribeRegions` method in the EC2 client: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ec2#Client.DescribeRegions

You can request all regions, or filter based on opt-in status.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to fetch the JSON that you mentioned, something like:

```
// endpoints holds the aws generated endpoints.json
type endpoints struct {
    Partitions []Partition `json:"partitions"`
}

type Partition struct {
    PartitionName string                 `json:"partitionName"`
    Regions       map[string]interface{} `json:"regions"`
    Services      map[string]Service     `json:"services"`
}

type Service struct {
    Endpoints map[string]interface{} `json:"endpoints"`
}

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Generating AWS regions")

    resp, err := http.Get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/master/codegen/smithy-aws-go-codegen/src/main/resources/software/amazon/smithy/aws/go/codegen/endpoints.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err.Error())
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err.Error())
    }

    e := endpoints{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &e)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err.Error())
    }

    // do something with e
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I am a bit late to the party.

I think I might have found a solution, using the [AWS Go SDK v1](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.45.15/aws/endpoints), there is some documentation that you can run the following:

```golang
import "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/endpoints"

EXAMPLE_CODE...

func describeRegions(service string) (map[string]endpoints.Region, bool) {
    sr, exists := endpoints.RegionsForService(endpoints.DefaultPartitions(), endpoints.AwsPartitionID, service)
    return sr, exists
}


func regionLooper() {
    regionList, exists := describeRegions("config") //This is the service you want to check. 
    if exists {
        for _, region := range regionList {
            r := region.ID()
            fmt.Printf("Switching to region: %s\n", r)
        }
    }
}
```

You can pass in the service as a string into the endpoint, unfortunately the  `endpoint.SERVICE` is deprecated such as `endpoint.ConfigServiceID`. So you will have to use the right variable from this [list](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/v1.45.15/aws/endpoints/dep_service_ids.go#L7).

Hope it helps!

Comment: I explicitly asked about SDK V2